# Iterative calculation with SymPy, solving the same equation for different values of parameters

Tags: python, sympy

I want to use sympy for electronic design calculations. I have a equation, which I solve for certain resistor values. I can only use standard resistor values, so I set the choosen value again in the equation, and get a final result.

```
'''Example calculations for LMZ22010 switching regulator'''
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')

from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol, Eq, symbols, var

syms = ['Rent, Renb, Vuvlo']

var(','.join(syms))

Eq_uvlo = Eq(Rent/Renb, (Vuvlo/1.274) -1).subs({Rent:47e3, Vuvlo:8})
Renb = solve(Eq_uvlo, Renb)[0]
print(Renb)
>>> 8902.46
```

Now i want to try 9100 for Renb. 
But i cannot calculate the final Vuvlo value, because it's already substituted.

```
Vuvlo = solve(Eq_uvlo.subs({Renb:9.1}), Vuvlo)
```

Is there any better way, to make a calculation like this?

Comment: Is it possible to make a function that accepts `Renb` as an argument?

Comment: Yes of course, i just prefer a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `Renb` as a symbol, but then assigned a value to it. This means you lost that symbol, you don't have a handle on it anymore. Use a different Python variable to hold any numerical value related to that symbol, like `Renb_sol` below.

Also, substitution of numerical values can be done later, *after* the solution is obtained. This allows you to use the same equation solving for different variables in it.

```
Eq_uvlo = Eq(Rent/Renb, (Vuvlo/1.274) -1)
Renb_sol = solve(Eq_uvlo, Renb)[0].subs({Rent: 47e3, Vuvlo: 8})
print(Renb_sol)
Vuvlo_sol = solve(Eq_uvlo, Vuvlo)[0].subs({Rent: 47e3, Renb: 9100})
print(Vuvlo_sol)
```

prints

```
8902.46803449301
7.85400000000000
```